# Adjust error bar width in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

This is my problem:

[image: My problem :-)]

I have a MATLAB plot with `errorbar` (all work right), but the width of the bars is too wide. There is a way to set the width of the bar?

If you look this image very carefully, you can see several lines reds and blues with the size that I would like (e.g., w = 0.25).

Any help is appreciate.

Comment: Both answers below does not work in Matlab 2014b to 2016a

Comment: From R2016b onwards, this can be achieved using `CapSize` option: https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/100333-how-do-i-change-the-width-of-the-horizontal-lines-at-top-and-bottom-of-error-bars-in-my-errorbar-plo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to access their `XData` property and modify them. Check [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/100333-how-do-i-change-the-width-of-the-horizontal-lines-at-top-and-bottom-of-error-bars-in-my-errorbar-plo) for an example by The Mathworks.

Concretely here is how to do it:

Generate an `errorbar` plot:

```
hf = figure;
X = 0:pi/10:pi;
Y = sin(X);
E = std(Y)*ones(size(X));

hErrBar = errorbar(X,Y,E);
```

Get the `XData` property as well as the left/right indices representing the horizontal lines of the error bars.

```
hb = get(hErrBar,'children');  
Xdata = get(hb(2),'Xdata');

temp = 4:3:length(Xdata);
temp(3:3:end) = [];

xleft = temp; xright = temp+1;
```

Modify the data as you wish and update the plot. For example, decrease the line length by 0.2 units

```
Xdata(xleft) = Xdata(xleft) + .1;
Xdata(xright) = Xdata(xright) - .1;

%// Update
set(hb(2),'Xdata',Xdata)
```

So for example,

Before:

[image]

And after:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found a code that modify the width of error bar.

Its use is very simple. After plotted an errorbar:

```
h = errorbar(X, Y, L, U, ...);
```

You have to call the function:

```
errorbar_tick(h,w);
```

As explained in the comments.

The code is:

```
function errorbar_tick(h,w,xtype)
%ERRORBAR_TICK Adjust the width of errorbars
%   ERRORBAR_TICK(H) adjust the width of error bars with handle H.
%      Error bars width is given as a ratio of X axis length (1/80).
%   ERRORBAR_TICK(H,W) adjust the width of error bars with handle H.
%      The input W is given as a ratio of X axis length (1/W). The result 
%      is independent of the x-axis units. A ratio between 20 and 80 is usually fine.
%   ERRORBAR_TICK(H,W,'UNITS') adjust the width of error bars with handle H.
%      The input W is given in the units of the current x-axis.
%
%   See also ERRORBAR
%
% Author: Arnaud Laurent
% Creation : Jan 29th 2009
% MATLAB version: R2007a
%
% Notes: This function was created from a post on the french forum :
% http://www.developpez.net/forums/f148/environnements-developpement/matlab/
% Author : Jerome Briot (Dut) 
%   http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/author/94805
%   http://www.developpez.net/forums/u125006/dut/
% It was further modified by Arnaud Laurent and Jerome Briot.

% Check numbers of arguments
error(nargchk(1,3,nargin))

% Check for the use of V6 flag ( even if it is depreciated ;) )
flagtype = get(h,'type');

% Check number of arguments and provide missing values
if nargin==1
    w = 80;
end

if nargin<3
   xtype = 'ratio';
end

% Calculate width of error bars
if ~strcmpi(xtype,'units')
    dx = diff(get(gca,'XLim')); % Retrieve x limits from current axis
    w = dx/w;                   % Errorbar width
end

% Plot error bars
if strcmpi(flagtype,'hggroup') % ERRORBAR(...)

    hh=get(h,'children');       % Retrieve info from errorbar plot
    x = get(hh(2),'xdata');     % Get xdata from errorbar plot

    x(4:9:end) = x(1:9:end)-w/2;    % Change xdata with respect to ratio
    x(7:9:end) = x(1:9:end)-w/2;
    x(5:9:end) = x(1:9:end)+w/2;
    x(8:9:end) = x(1:9:end)+w/2;

    set(hh(2),'xdata',x(:)) % Change error bars on the figure

else  % ERRORBAR('V6',...)

    x = get(h(1),'xdata');      % Get xdata from errorbar plot

    x(4:9:end) = x(1:9:end)-w/2;    % Change xdata with respect to the chosen ratio
    x(7:9:end) = x(1:9:end)-w/2;
    x(5:9:end) = x(1:9:end)+w/2;
    x(8:9:end) = x(1:9:end)+w/2;

    set(h(1),'xdata',x(:))  % Change error bars on the figure

end
```